# Spring PetClinic <spring:url ....../> encoding for very url

Tags: java, spring, url, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am implementing the Spring Pet Clinic Sample project given [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/)

Implementation [here](http://gopetclinic.cfapps.io/)

In the home page all the urls are encoded by `<spring:url />` tag. I just want to confirm that is it a good programming practice to encode the links, even the simple navigation urls by the spring:url tag or is it done for a specific reason?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice. That tag is a Spring JSP tag for creating URLs with enhancements for JSTL `c:url`.
 `<c:url>` tag is used to create a url and it is helpful in the case when cookies is turned off by the client, and you would be required to rewrite URLs that will be returned from a jsp page. 
The rewritten URL will encode the session ID if necessary to provide persistent sessions.

For example, your URL will be displayed as:

```
<c:url value="a.jsp">

/context/a.jsp // when cookies is enabled
/context/a.jsp;jsessionid=B01F432.... // when cookie is disabled
```

This way, the servlet container can track the user requests. Another important thing is that `c:url`  will prefix the context root, so you don't need to write your root context prefix everywhere.

Like I said, `<spring:url>` contains some enhancements over JSTL like encoded URI template variables for example.

```
<spring:url value="/url/path/{variableName}">
   <spring:param name="variableName" value="more than JSTL c:url" />
 </spring:url>
```

Results in: /currentApplicationContext/url/path/more%20than%20JSTL%20c%3Aurl

See more details in here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucas, I have just one doubt what if the session is not created I've just visited the index page of the app. In this scenario what will the spring:url tag return.

Comment: When you request *first time* your links with c:url tag will be rewrite to add jsessionid parameter. At this moment  the server isn't sure if the client supports cookies or not, and so it generates a cookie as well as the jsessionid on the URL.